# How to fit a single model to several independent datasets in spatstat?

Tags: r, spatstat

I would like to fit a single model to several independent datasets in `R` using the `spatstat` package. Here, I have 3 independent datasets (`ppp` objects called `NMJ1`, `NMJ2`, and `NMJ3`), to which I want to fit a common model. The way to go should be to use the `mppm` function:

```
data <- listof(NMJ1,NMJ2,NMJ3)
data <- hyperframe(X=1:3, Points=data)
r <- matrix(c(120, 240, 240, 90), nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
model <- mppm(Points ~marks*abs(sqrt(x^2+y^2)), data, MultiStrauss(r))
```

In the model I am fitting, the intensity is a function of the distance to the center of the window and I supposed a `MultiStrauss` interaction scheme.

However, the `mppm` function is going to fit each dataset independently. When typing `subfits(model)`, the fitted trend coefficients are the same for each dataset, but not the gamma coefficients. Similarly, in plotting the results of `simulate(model)`, I observe significant and consistent differences between the 3 plots.

What is the best way to handle independent datasets (repetition of samples from the same model) in `spatstat` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a **bug**.

Your code is correct for this purpose. (Namely, when we want the same interaction coefficients to apply to all of the point patterns.)

There is a **bug** in the function `subfits` in the package `spatstat.core`.

The fitted model returned by `mppm` is correct, but the list of sub-models returned by `subfits` is partially incorrect.

The bug will be fixed shortly, in the development version `spatstat.core 2.3-0.011` available from [the GitHub repository](https://github.com/spatstat/spatstat.core)